# rename process using pm2 programmatic api

Tags: node.js, electron, pm2

I have an electron app which uses pm2 to start some apps using the pm2 module.Everything is fine.However I am trying to implement the following feature:Renaming an app you have started.I know that using the cli I can do the following:

`pm2 restart app --name"New name"`;

So I found the `pm2.restart` function which takes an Object and a callback as a parameter.So I tried this:

```
var options = {app:"Blogsport App",name:"New name"};
var callback = function(err){
   if(err) {console.log('Failed')}
   else {console.log('App renamed')}
};

pm2.restart(options,callback);
```

This will always log "App renamed".However If I do `pm2 list` I see that the app has not be renamed.Is there anything I can do to rename an app without deleting it and start it again with a different name?

Comment: try adding the `--update-env` param in options

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: just for a test you could write something like `exec('pm2 restart  app --name "New name"', function(err, stdout, stderr){ if(err) console.log(err);}` etc.. See if it's working that way, if so then it might be a bug ? you will need child_proc `var exec = require('child_process').exec;`

Comment: I will be able to test in an hour or so

Comment: I know I can do this with exec by replacing app with my app name but I would prefer to do this using the pm2 if that's possible

Comment: So just looking at restart can you try : `pm2.restart(options,{rawArgs : ["--update-env"] },callback);` ? or add the `rawArgs` attribut in the `options` variable.. As I say I will be able to test in 1 hour : https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/API.js#L1434

Comment: OK .I tried both methods but to no avail.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

you can try this:

```
pm2 restart id --name newName
```

Example: your id is 1 , then you can type : pm2 restart 1 --name development

Comment: If you've previously dumped your processes I would suggest running `pm2 save` afterwards to synchronize your changes with saved process list.

Answer (score 21):

you can do

---

```
pm2 delete id|name  
pm2 start app.js -n newname
```

or

```
pm2 restart id|name -n newname
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pm2 ls
```

to see your app id

then you have two options
delete and start again

```
pm2 delete <id> 
pm2 start index.js --name newname
```

or just restart to keep same id

```
pm2 restart <id> --name newname
```